# Java inputstream read twice

Tags: java, spring, inputstream

I can read the first line from the input stream and store it into string variable.Then how do i read remaining lines and copy to the another input stream to process further.

```
        InputStream is1=null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String todecrypt = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            todecrypt =  reader.readLine(); // this will read the first line
             String line1=null;
             while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null){ //loop will run from 2nd line
                 is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(line1.getBytes()); 
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());

        }

        System.out.println("to decrpt str==="+todecrypt);
```

then i will use is1 as anothor inputstream from second line and my sample file sending here

[sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLvJ0.png)

Comment: please provide some code you have tried

Comment: i posted the code i have tried, can you look into it.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html

Comment: after you read the first line from the input stream, you can handle it off to others to read. no new `InputStream` is required.

Comment: @jerry Chin Can i use same inputStream to send another class and read it again from second line?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Jerry Chin's comment into a full answer:

you can just do

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String todecrypt = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        todecrypt =  reader.readLine(); // this will read the first line
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("to decrpt str==="+todecrypt);

    //This will output the first character of the second line
    System.out.println((char)inputStream.read());
```

You can imagine an Inputstream as a row of characters. Reading a character is removing the first character in the row. After that you can still use the Inputstream to read more characters. The BufferedReader just reads the InputStream until it finds a '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using readers (`BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`) they read data from original stream (`inputStream` variable) as chars, not as bytes.  So after you read first line from reader original stream will be empty. It's because reader will try to fill whole char buffer (by default it's `defaultCharBufferSize = 8192` chars). So you really can't use original stream anymore, because it has no data anymore. You have to read remaining chars from existing reader, and create a new InputStream with remaining data. Code example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream("line 1 \r\n line 2 \r\n line 3 \r\n line 4".getBytes());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bais));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) > 0)
        sb.append((char)c);
    String remainder = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("`" + remainder + "`");
    InputStream streamWithRemainingLines = new ByteArrayInputStream(remainder.getBytes());
}
```

Note that `\r\n`'s aren't lost